# somebody blocked wallpaper change access

Tags: windows-registry, desktop-customization

I've tried with desktop's registry settings, but somebody might have hacked the registry, abolishing the access to change desktop wallpapers.

Can somebody figure out what's the problem with it?

Windows 7

Comment: You should update your question, and include, what version of Windows your using.  If you are connected to domain, you should mention that too, thats important information.

Answer (score 1):

This may a group policy, this is to be expected in a corporate environment

- Open the Group Policy Editor (Windows key + R, type "gpedit.msc")
- Navigate to User Configuration / Administrative Templates / Desktop / Desktop
- Double click on "Desktop Wallpaper" on the right
- Logout and logon again and see if there is any change
- If you cannot change the settings and the usual control panel wallpaper controls are grayed out, you're probably out of luck because the network administator prevented you from changing this. Some companies force users to have the company logo as their wallpaper.

Here are some detailed explanations, intended for an administrator of such a company, school or organization:

http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/03/best-practice-using-group-policy-to-configure-desktop-wallpaper-background/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: OK thanks for the warning I'll include the interesting items directly in the answer